# Is there a difference between ModelState and ViewData.ModelState?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, modelstate, viewdata

In some ASP.NET MVC code examples, I see references to `ModelState.IsValid`, and in other examples I see references to `ViewData.ModelState.IsValid`.

In my initial research, I see:

- `ModelState` is a public property in `Controller` class.
- `ViewData` is a public property in `ControllerBase` class.

Is there a difference between the two? Why have both?

Comment: Same thing. Just like `System.Int32` and `Int32`. Some people just like to use a fully qualified namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They reference the exact same thing, if you look at the code for `System.Web.Mvc.Controller` class you will see the implementation for `ModelState` is:

```
   public ModelStateDictionary ModelState
    {
      get
      {
        return this.ViewData.ModelState;
      }
    }
```

I would say it is simply there for easy of use in your own Controller implementations.

Comment: Yes, in my own tests I see that both 'ModelState.IsValid' and 'ViewData.ModelState.IsValid' are both the same ModelStateDictionary.  And ModelStateDictionary holds ModelState objects.

Answer (score 1):

They're one and the same, and you *could* use `ViewData.ModelState.Errors` in your controller - having it as a property on `ControllerBase` is really just a convenience, allowing you to shorten it to `ModelState.Errors` (and the even more often used `ModelState.IsValid`).

Although the main use of `ModelState` from an "end developer"'s perspective is in the controller, `ViewData` is used as a container for all data that's communicated between the controller and the view. Which is why it also needs to include `ModelState` - because, although you'd rarely use it directly in the view, `ModelState` is where e.g. many of the HtmlHelper methods actually get the values from by default when rendering the view from a POST action - rather than `Model`.